# Dependency management in java

Tags: java, dependencies, dependency-management

I implemented a tool and I want to make it open source.

The problem is that my tool has some dependencies (binaries/. jar files).

How can solve this problem, so that the person who downloads my source code, for example to extend it to a new feature, doesn't have to care of the dependencies?

Should i write the dependencies in the MANIFEST as relative path, relative to my source code or something like that?

Comment: use maven within your code or compile it using shade or something.

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your project into a maven project and then put your source code to githup or something similar. If your dependencies are not available on the web but instead your other projects, you should also place them on the web so maven can download them for anyone who wants to use.